# What happens if we blowup $\mathbb{P}^2$ at more than 9 points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For $s\leq 8$, if we blowup $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $s$ general points, we get a Del Pezzo surface. I am wondering what happens if $s\geq 9$? How does this 8 being calculated?

Comment: Don't do it! P^2 can take only so many blowups! If you overdo it... it'll blow up!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Interesting! Mind elaborate more on this?

Comment: I was joking ;-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Ah great :) How was the number 8 correspond to anti-canonical being ample?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical class of the blow-up in question is $K_X = -3h + \sum_{i=1} e_i$, where $e_i$ are the exceptional curves.  In particular, this gives $(-K_X)^2 = 9 -k$.  If $k \geq 9$, this is less than or equal $0$.  But an ample divisor must have positive self-intersection!   So there is no way it's del Pezzo.

Note that positive self-intersection doesn't imply ampleness; you have to actually check that it works for the smaller cases.  For $1 \leq s \leq 6$ in fact $-K_X$ is very ample, while for $s = 7,8$ if memory serves you get $-K_X$ not very ample, but $-2K_X$ is.  At least the first of these is proved in Hartshorne, in the chapter about the cubic surface (V.4 maybe?  I'm afraid I don't have the book in front of me)

The case of $k \geq 9$ points has very interesting geometry, and some quite basic looking conjectures (most famously Nagata's conjecture) are still open.  One place to read a bit about this is here: http://www.uni-due.de/~mat903/preprints/nagata1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the clean answer and the nice reference!